# Want to extract the QR value from firebase database but the snapshot prints nil

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to extract the QR value which is on firebase database QR Values->year->month->day->QR : value
[image]

```
func GetQR() {
    let date = getDate()

    let year =  String(describing: date.year)
    let month = String(describing:date.month)
    let day = String(describing:date.day)

    ref = Database.database().reference().child("QR Values").child(year).child(month).child(day)
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        // Get user value
        let value = snapshot.value as? String


            print(value)

    })
    { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    }
```

The printed snapshot is nil.

Comment: have also added last child('QR') in the query.

Comment: the value is a dict ["QR": "kUX...."] not a string

Comment: For your question on refactoring, have a look at [Composition versus Inheritance](http://www.artima.com/designtechniques/compoinh.html) and ask any questions about your code over on the sister site: [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You still need to look up the `QR` property in the [snapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DataSnapshot#childsnapshotforpath) that you get from the database:

```
ref = Database.database().reference().child("QR Values").child(year).child(month).child(day)
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    let value = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "QR").value as? String
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the variable ***year*** , ***month*** and ***day*** are optional and the values of  ***year*** , ***month*** and ***day*** in firebase database are not optional, it results **nil**. So, the solution is to remove optional.

```
   func GetQR() {

    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute], from: date)

    let year =  "\(String(describing: components.year!))"
    let month = "\(String(describing: components.month!))"
    let day = "\(String(describing: components.day!))"

ref = Database.database().reference().child("QR Values").child(year).child(month).child(day)
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

    // Get user value
    let value = snapshot.value as? String


        print(value)

})
{ (error) in
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}

}
```